# How to send an adress of procedure to another function as a parameter in Lazarus?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have form, where i programmatically create button in FormCreate procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
...    
   but := TButton.Create(Form1);
   ...
   but.OnClick := @OnMyButClick;
```

Where OnMyButClick is declared in

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
...
procedure OnMyButClick(Sender: TObject);
```

All works fine, but i want to create this button not in my main unit, but in another unit and send all parameters there. All parameters send ok (like left,top..), but i can't send adress of OnMyButClick procedure to my new procedure CreateMyButton();

Q: How to send an adress of procedure OnMyButClick to another function as a parameter in Lazarus?

Comment: `procedure SetNotifyEventHandler(AEventHandler: TNotifyEvent; AButton: TButton);` and `SetNotifyEventHandler(@OnMyButClick, MyBut);`

Answer (score 2):

```
procedure CreateMyButton( ... ; ClickEvent: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  ... ;
  Button.OnClick:=ClickEvent;
end;
```

call it like this:

```
CreateMyButton( ... , @OnMyButClick);
```